# Open ERP 7.0 + CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, odoo, centos6, openerp-7

We have an OpenERP server running on port 8069 that randomly stopped working. When visiting localhost:8069, I receive a "No handler found." error.

I have looked on the internet and most resolutions seem to be module related, specifically the "web" module; however, my openerp-server.log file only shows the below information.

```
2014-10-23 18:17:38,732 29406 INFO ? werkzeug: 10.1.10.109 - - [23/Oct/2014 18:17:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2014-10-23 18:17:39,104 29406 DEBUG ? openerp.service.cron: cron0 polling for jobs
2014-10-23 18:17:42,299 786 DEBUG ? openerp.service.cron: cron0 polling for jobs
```

Can anybody assist with troubleshooting this problem a bit more, as we have customer records that need to be accessed on this machine as soon as possible, and I am at a loss.

Comment: I hace the same problem with Odoo v8

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the server has some problem that makes it fail to start. Probably your log has more lines and they can shed light on the problem.

When you start the server, by default it doesn't load any database. That is done on first access. only then you may be able see errors initializing the database, such as a module failing to load.

You can try starting indicating a specific database to force it's loading upon server start:

```
./openerp-server -d my-database
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I ended up figuring out what was going on upon a bunch of Google. It ended up being the permissions on a couple different folders that OpenERP was supposed to own. We run another piece of software on there that ended up taking ownership of these folders (root folder + OpenERP tmp folder). A simple chown openerp:openerp on these folders solved the issue.

Comment: @m3asmi Are you still having issues with this?

Comment: @wtaggin I don't have that problem anymore